# Convert JavaScript test cases back to test constructor

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, recording, testcafe, converters

I have recorded several test cases using TestCafe Studio and converted them to JavaScript to run them on Jenkins and TeamCity. However, our in-house application is being constantly updated, so we need to update a couple of our test cases as well.

I need to continue recording of my tests and convert them to the original state before converting them to JavaSript, so I can use the test constructor and recorder. But I didn't find this converter. Can I convert my JavaScript test cases back to the original format so that I can re-record and update them?

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to convert a JavaScript test back to the testcafe format. The reason is JavaScript format tests support any custom JavaScript code you would like to write there. And TestCafe format may not support some of it. Instead, I would suggest you keep your original TestCafe tests after conversion to JavaScript in order to be able to re-record and re-convert them as needed.